# How to check if column of datetime values is in a list of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

So I have a column with a list of dates in it.  I have a list/array with a set of specific dates in it.  I want to assign a new column in my dataframe with true/false as to whether or not the specific date was in the list.  I have the following, but it doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

```
__DATELIST = [date(2017, 7, 4), date(2016, 7, 4), ...]

def isholiday(x):
   return x in __DATELIST

df['isholiday'] = df['date'].apply(isholiday)
```

Any thoughts?  The above is always false.

Comment: What is the datatype of `df['date']`?

Comment: df['date'] says dtime is datetime64

Comment: So they presumably won't be equal to `datetime.date()` values

Answer (score 3):

Convert to `datetime` using `to_datetime`, and then use `isin` to get your mask:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime([date(2017, 7, 4), date(2016, 7, 4), ...])
df['isholiday'] = df['date'].isin(dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `datetime.datetime` objects instead of `datetime.date` objects to construct your list of dates. Your data types need to be equivalent.

Comment: You're on the right track, but this doesn't really answer the question.